# How can I solve strict mode warning without removing strict mode in react index.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strict-mode

When I use `<Button />` in below form then it says

`Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of RefFindNode which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.`

Even I used useRef, still it is showing this warning. So can I fix it without removing <React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode> in index file

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import { Button, Container, Form, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import Layout from '../layout/Layout'

const Login = () => {

    let btn = useRef(null)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(btn);
    })

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Container className="auth-form segment">
                <Form>
                    <Form.Field 
                        label="Email"
                        control={Input}
                        placeholder="example@gmail.com"
                        name="email"
                    />
                    <Form.Field 
                        label="Password"
                        control={Input}
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                    />
                    <Button content="Login" ref={btn} primary/>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

Instead, why won't you do something like (in index.js file):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
   return <React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>;
}
else
{
   return <App />;
}
```

You can use some other flag as you wish...
Just an idea.

Comment: So why is that? In StrictMode we can see the potential warnings. Warnings tell us to make a change in code to improve performance. Isn't it? But,  why can't we fix that?